# What's the difference between rxjava2's Maybe and Optional?

Tags: java, rx-java, option-type, rx-java2

The doc says

> Conceptually, it is a union of Single and Completable providing the
>   means to capture an emission pattern where there could be 0 or 1 item
>   or an error signalled by some reactive source.

But I am not sure what it truly means. It seems it is java8's `Optional`.

The following two codes have the same result , but I don't know what `Maybe` can do and `Optional` cannot (or cumbersome) do.

```
  @Test
  public void testMaybe1() {
    Observable.just(3, 2, 1, 0, -1)
      .map(i -> {
        try {
          int result = 6 / i;
          return Maybe.just(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return Maybe.empty();
        }
      })
      .blockingForEach(maybe -> {
          logger.info("result = {}", maybe.blockingGet());
        }
      );
  }


  @Test
  public void testMaybe2() {
    Observable.just(3, 2, 1, 0, -1)
      .map(i -> {
        try {
          int result = 6 / i;
          return Optional.of(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return Optional.empty();
        }
      })
      .blockingForEach(opt -> {
          logger.info("result = {}", opt.orElse(null));
        }
      );
  }
```

The results are the same :

```
result = 2
result = 3
result = 6
result = null
result = -6
```

In rxJava1 , My API used to return `Observable<Optional<T>>` , Is it a bad smell ? Should I change to `Observable<Maybe<T>>` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Maybe` is a wrapper around an **operation/event** that may have either

1. A single result
2. No result
3. Error result

However Optional is a wrapper around a **value** that may either be

1. Present
2. Absent

In your example, in the `map` operation, the computation is synchronous (i.e. `6/i` is synchronous and can result in a value immediately) and you want to propagate a value (if division is possible) or empty value (if division is not possible). Hence using `Optional` makes more sense.

There are however other options also:

- If you want to propagate why division is not possible then you would want to report the exception that occurred. In such a case using `Maybe` will make more sense.
- If you are not interested in both empty value and reason of error, then you simply want to skip propagating those results. In such a scenario I would use a `flatMap` instead of `map`. I will then not have to use any of `Optional` or `Maybe`.

  ```
  .flatMap(i -> { 
    try { 
      int result = 6 / i; 
      return Observable.just(result); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      return Observable.empty(); 
    } 
  })
  ```

`Maybe` is also useful when you have an `Observable` that can emit multiple values but you are interested in, let's say, only the first one and hence you use the `firstElement()` operator on the Observable. This returns a Maybe because either there is a single value, or there is no value (if source Observable does not emit any value before completing) or there is an error (if source Observable errors before emitting any value).

Comment: Does not have to be an asynchronous event, can be synchronous.

Comment: @DaveMoten - Point taken and changes made. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

`Maybe` is a lazy stream of zero or one things (and being a stream can result in an error). `Optional` is not lazy, it it is either present or absent. There is no sense of deferred calculation with an `Optional` whereas there is with `Maybe`.

Answer (score 6):

The difference relevant to your question is that `Maybe` can propagate error while `Optional` cannot - in your example one cannot distinguish between error and empty result. If error handling is important, `Optional` is useless, while `Maybe` has `Maybe.error(Throwable)`. API-wise, for your use case I would prefer `Single` to `Maybe` - because it yields either Error or single Result, so return type would be `Observable<Single<T>>`

Answer (score 2):

RxJava 2 targets Java 6. This means there is no builtin `Optional` support guaranteed, and they have to bring their own. Similar to how they have to bring their own `Function` types.

If your application/library only supports Java >= 8 you can use whatever suits you better.